# Is there a way to approximate a polynomial as another, binary-coefficient polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, binary, approximation-theory

Let's say I have a polynomial:
$$p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n$$
where $x \in \mathbb C$.

Does there exist theory and/or methods on approximating $p$ as:
$$p(x) \approx \hat p(x) = \sum_{m=0}^M b_n x^m$$
where $b_n \in \{0,1\}$ or perhaps $b_n \in \{-1,1\}$? I am prepared to allow $M \gg N$ if that is necessary to get a reasonable approximation.

Bonus generalisation: $b_n$ being discrete, not necessarily with a finite alphabet, would also be interesting.

Comment: In which sense do you want $p$ to be approximated (maybe minimizing the maximal distance on $[0,1]$, or the integral of the square of the difference ...) ? For example, how would you approximate $p(x) = 1000$ ?

Comment: Good question that I hadn't given too much thought yet. I have added a few details to the question now, notably that $x$ is complex.
Then I think approximating in the sense of minimising $\|p - \hat p\|_2$ would be useful.

Comment: How about up to a real scalar constant?

Comment: @rrogers I am not completely sure what you mean?

Comment: I think they mean that, when $x=0$ your polynomial will take the value $a_0$ which is either 0 or 1. So you certainly can't make every polynomial using your construction.

Comment: @Simon Yes that is typical.  What I was getting too was seeing if the Walsh-Hadamard transform fit into the question.  But that's really time domain averaging at successively small intervals.  OTOH: applying it in the frequency domain spreads the result out over the whole interval in the time domain.  The truth is: I don't think it works but can't quite capture  why.